# Variogram to constrain kernel density bandwidth

Tags: density-estimation, variogram

I have linear structures transformed into points and spatially distributed like this:
[image]

I want to perform a kernel density so that zones with lots of structures present high density. The problem is that I have to define a distance (bandwidth) for the kernel when calculating the density (on ArcGIS).

For that reason, I want to use a variogram to constrain the distance at which most of my structures are correlated. I would do the analysis at 2 azimuths (perpendicular + parallel to the structures). However, I don't know what variables to use for the tail and the head properties (on SGeMS). I guess it should be the distance between neighboring structures... and the variance on the Y axis (depending on on the lags), would show how these inter-distances vary. But I don't know how to approach it.

Any idea?

Comment: If you do not get an answer here I suggest looking for a site specialising in GIS

Comment: It's difficult to see how a variogram would give you relevant information, in part because it will be sensitive to the resolution which you use to discretize these linear structures.  Often kernel widths are chosen by optimizing some objective, such as a cross-validation.  Roughly, that amounts to playing around with the width until the kernel smooth is appropriate for your analysis.

Comment: I see, thanks for the indications. If we imagine the approach is right, does it matter the points analyzed are only from the structures or should the "gap" between them (where no points exist) should be filled in to get a more homogeneous grid?